# Google App Engine Django and HTML5

Tags: django, html, google-app-engine

I'm keen to get some of the new controllers - like sliders etc and the Canvas Elements into Google App Engine with the Django framework. Is there a smart way to do this? Or should I siply just revert to using the raw HTML5 a .html. I did'nt find anything pertaining to Django and HTML5 templates for things such as sliders.

Answer (score 1):

Writing custom html for forms in Django is a bad idea. You should use [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/) that implement the new HTML 5 features.

HTML 5 widgets aren't included in Django at the moment, so you could write them yourself, or try something like [django-html5](https://github.com/rhec/django-html5/blob/master/html5/forms/widgets.py) (I haven't used it myself, I just searched for *django html5 widgets*)